# Need help designing big database update process

Tags: sql-server, architecture, ado.net

We have a database with ~100K business objects in it. Each object has about 40 properties which are stored amongst 15 tables. I have to get these objects, perform some transforms on them and then write them to a different database (with the same schema.)
This is ADO.Net 3.5, SQL Server 2005.

We have a library method to write a single property. It figures out which of the 15 tables the property goes into, creates and opens a connection, determines whether the property already exists and does an insert or update accordingly, and closes the connection.

My first pass at the program was to read an object from the source DB, perform the transform, and call the library routine on each of its 40 properties to write the object to the destination DB. Repeat 100,000 times. Obviously this is egregiously inefficent.

What are some good designs for handling this type of problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This is exactly the sort of thing that SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) is good for. It's documented in Books Online, same as SQL Server is.

Comment: +1 exactly - ETL (extract - transform - load) at its finest :-)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I would say that you need to forget your client-side library, and do it all in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

How many times do you need to do this? If only once, and it can run unattended, I see no reason why you shouldn't reuse your existing client code. Automating the work of human beings is what computers are for. If it's inefficient, I know that sucks, but if you're going to do a week of work setting up a SSIS package, that's inefficient too. Plus, your client-side solution could contain business logic or validation code that you'd have to remember to carry over to SQL.

You might want to research [Create_Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189524.aspx), moving your client code across the network to reside on your SQL box. This will avoid network latency, but could destabilize your SQL Server.

Comment: I need to do it about once a week and currently takes about 13 hours. It can run unattended and I normally start the process before going home. But it bothers me to have such an inefficient process and I'd really like to make it more elegant. Hence my plea for a more efficient design.

Comment: If I were you, I'd look to optimize your existing client code. I bet there's tons of opportunities for optimization. For instance, are you executing a database command for each and every object property, or one per object? Are you connection-pooling or opening/closing a connection with each call?

By my calculations, you're only getting ~two objects per second. With a couple of careful optimizations, some index tuning, etc, you can probably get that down to just a couple of hours, which is reasonable and won't require a rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Bad news: you have many options

use flatfile transformations: Extract all the data into flatfiles, manipulate them using grep, awk, sed, c, perl into the required insert/update statements and execute those against the target database

PRO: Fast; CON: extremly ugly ... nightmare for maintanance, don't do this if you need this for longer then a week. And a couple dozens of executions

use pure sql: I don't know much about sql server, but I assume it has away to access one database from within the other, so one of the fastes ways to do this is to write it as a collection of 'insert / update / merge statements fed with select statements.

PRO: Fast, one technology only; CON: Requires direct connection between databases You might reach the limit of SQL or the available SQL knowledge pretty fast, depending on the kind of transformation.

use t-sql, or whatever iterative language the database provides, everything else is similiar to pure sql aproach.

PRO: pretty fast since you don't leave the database CON: I don't know t-sql, but if it is anything like PL/SQL it is not the nicest language to do complex transformation.

use a high level language (Java, C#, VB ...): You would load your data into proper business objects manipulate those and store them in the database. Pretty much what you seem to be doing right now, although it sounds there are better ORMs available, e.g. nhibernate

use a ETL Tool: There are special tools for extracting, transforming and loading data. They often support various databases. And have many strategies readily available for deciding if an update or insert is in place.

PRO: Sorry, you'll have to ask somebody else for that, I so far have nothing but bad experience with those tools.

CON: A highly specialized tool, that you need to master. I my personal experience: slower in implementation and execution of the transformation then handwritten SQL. A nightmare for maintainability, since everything is hidden away in proprietary repositories, so for IDE, Version Control, CI, Testing you are stuck with whatever the tool provider gives you, if any.

PRO: Even complex manipulations can be implemented in a clean maintainable way, you can use all the fancy tools like good IDEs, Testing Frameworks, CI Systems to support you while developing the transformation.

CON: It adds a lot of overhead (retrieving the data, out of the database, instanciating the objects, and marshalling the objects back into the target database. I'd go this way if it is a process that is going to be around for a long time.

Building on the last option you could further glorify the architectur by using messaging and webservices, which could be relevant if you have more then one source database, or more then one target database. Or you could manually implement a multithreaded transformer, in order to gain through put. But I guess I am leaving the scope of your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with John, SSIS is the way to go for any repeatable process to import large amounts of data. It should be much faster than the 30 hours you are currently getting. You could also write pure t-sql code to do this if the two database are on the same server or are linked servers. If you go the t-sql route, you may need to do a hybrid of set-based and looping code to run on batches (of say 2000 records at a time) rather than lock up the table for the whole time a large insert would take.

Comment: And one of the things that HLGEM is implying is that SSIS will do the batching sorts of thing for you, especially SSIS 2008.